# Where the function ap_run_pre_connection in Apache httpd source code?

Tags: apache

I'm reading the source code of the Apache2.2 and I found that when I use the prefork module,it call the `ap_process_connection` to deal with a connection and in this method it calls the `ap_run_pre_connection`.
When it comes to here,I can find neither `ap_run_pre_connection` nor `pre_connection` (I find a macro named AP_DECLARE_HOOK, it linked the `ap` and `_hook_` before the name `pre_connection`).
Where can I find the next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the modules that participate in this hook by looking for ap_hook_pre_connection.

AP_IMPLEMENT_HOOK_RUN_ALL(int,pre_connection,(conn_rec *c, void *csd),(c, csd),OK,DECLINED)

AP_IMPLEMENT_HOOK_RUN_ALL means multiple modules that called ap_hook_pre_connection() will be run until an error is returned

```
/**
 * Implement an Apache core hook that runs until one of the functions
 * returns something other than ok or decline. That return value is
 * then returned from the hook runner. If the hooks run to completion,
 * then ok is returned. Note that if no hook runs it would probably be
 * more correct to return decline, but this currently does not do
 * so. The implementation is called ap_run_<i>name</i>.
```

The actual impl of ap_run_pre_connection is just a macro that loops through a linked list of registered functions. See apr_hooks.h